# Gatsbyjs load different header in layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

I have 2 header components in my project.

The layout component is under src/layouts/index.jsx

```
const Layout = ({ children, data }) => (
............code here...........
)
```

I need to load different Header component depending on what page users are on.

How can I do it?

Comment: What version of React Router?

Comment: @TylerSebastian I'm not using React Router, and not sure whether I need to use it or not. As it is only for SPA, but Gatsbyjs is a multiple page website generator. so literally I have many pages. Not sure whether React Router would work in this approach.

Comment: you tagged it with React Router...

Comment: @TylerSebastian sorry mate, I'm not sure whether I could use React Router to solve it or not, so I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `location` prop and check for the `pathname` before rendering your component.

Something like this:

```
const Layout = ({ children, data, location }) => (
  <div>
    {location.pathname === '/home' &&
      <FirstHeader />
    }
    {location.pathname === '/page-2' &&
      <SecondHeader />
    }
  </div>
);
```

Gatsby actually use `react-router` internally for their route system so you can use the same logic here.